# LINUX - como usar uma string como delimitador no comando cut

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Como utilizo uma string no comando cut? já tentei com:
`cut -d"String" -f1` porém ele diz que só é possível com um carácter único.

Comment: O que `man cut` diz sobre isso? Por que você precisa de uma palavra como delimitador?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com cut, acredito não ser possivel, mas pode utilizar o awk:

```
awk -F"string" '{print $1}' file
```

Comment: Perfeito! vou pesquisar mais sobre esse awk.